# Activating infrared camera causes PI Zero W to crash and reboot

Tags: camera, crash

I have a PI Zero W and a camera module that came with 2 infrared lamps. It is this one or something very similar:
https://www.arducam.com/product/arducam-ov5647-5mipi-camera-module-for-jetson-nano-with-ir-cut-led/

When I use the camera alone with `raspistill` or `raspivid` - it works okeyish (though video does lag every second even with low settings and bitrate set to 2 000 000). But when I attached the infrared lamps - Pi crashes after 1-2 photos or whenever I try to launch video stream.

From searching this stack, I think it may be the power supply (I'm using my old charger from a cheap smartphone). Is there any way to diagnose this problem more reliably? The lamps also come with a small screw that is labeled as adjustable resistance in some marketing materials, though I can't  seem to find more info.

Comment: `Is there any way to diagnose this problem more reliably?` ... yes there is .... maybe you should be asking ... `what is one of the ways to diagnose this problem more reliably?` ... that could be answered `measure the power supply voltage`

Comment: How much power do the camera plus IR lamps need?  How much are you supplying?

Comment: `I'm using my old charger from a cheap smartphone` - use a better power supply, guaranteed that's the issue

Comment: I don't have anything to measure power-draw with, but I got a more powerful adapter and camera works now with both IR lamps attached.

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed, power supply was to blame. According to info from the web, Pi Zero W may draw up to 1.3 amps, while a cheap charger may be supplying less than 0.5 amps. Model 4 can draw up to 3 amps, which very few standard chargers will supply, lucky I got Raspberrys own power supply for that one.